# Divisible module over an integral domain is not projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I was reading the proof of the fact that  $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module. And I was wondering if we could say that any divisible module over an integral domain is not projective?

Comment: You'll need to exclude the case where the integral domain is a field, and you'll need to exclude the zero module.

Comment: So excluding those cases, how could one prove this?

Comment: A projective module (say $P$) is a direct summand in a free module (say $F$). Now pick a non-zero element $x\in P$. Write $x$ as a linear combination of the basis in $F$. Then recall that for every $a\in R$, $a\ne 0$ there is $y\in P$ such that $x=ay$. This shows that the coefficients of the linear combination are divisible by every non-zero element. This leads to every non-zero element of $R$ is invertible, so $R$ is a field.